# How do I put live updates into GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, rest, dynamic-layer

I have a GeoServer with all of the static maps, stores, layers, etc already.
How can I dynamically (at runtime, ideally via REST) add / remove features so they are added / removed from maps served by GeoServer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the underlying datastore then the new features will show up in new maps. Note this will not work if you are caching tiles either in the browser or GeoWebCache.

Comment: How can I change the underlying datastore? Are there REST endpoints for adding / removing from the datastore? I'm not finding documentation for datastore modification.

Comment: you don't need to change the datastore, just add to it's contents - there is no REST endpoint, it depends on the store but usually you would add a row to the table